# Problem with deployment of AutoML model via docker using automl model server: "Not found: Op type not registered 'DecodeProtoSparseV4'"

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, tensorflow-serving, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-automl

I have trained model in GC AutoML tables and deploying it using this instructions https://cloud.google.com/automl-tables/docs/model-export

I have exported model folder with saved_model.pb inside and running docker

```
docker run -v `pwd`/my_model:/models/default/0000001 -p 8000:8080 -it gcr.io/cloud-automl-tables-public/model_server
```

couldn't start with error

```
Loading servable: {name: default version: 1} failed: Not found: Op type not registered 'DecodeProtoSparseV4' in binary running on 61894e77342e. Make sure the Op and Kernel are registered in the binary running in this process. Note that if you are loading a saved graph which used ops from tf.contrib, accessing (e.g.) `tf.contrib.resampler` should be done before importing the graph, as contrib ops are lazily registered when the module is first accessed.
```

I have another model that was trained couple weeks ago and it's working fine, but fresh model is failing with same deployment steps.

As I see it could be a problem with tooling versions of environments for training model and for deployment but I don't have any control or information about which versions of tensorflow or struct2tensor is used.

I managed to start docker with model using lastest s2t_tf_serving, but still /predict request fails with error.

Is there something I could do to make it work?

**UPD**

With new version of model_server the issue disappeared.

Comment: This issue is more related to Tensorflow and Docker. Please, edit your tags. Also, this post may help you in your question. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/38597

Comment: @MariCruzR thanks for response, issue as itself probably related to tensorflow, but I am not using tensorflow directly, training of the model occurs on google cloud service and docker container for deployment provided by google cloud service, I have none control over what libraries are used inside.

Answer (score 1):

Can you delete the model_server image and try with latest

```
docker run -v `pwd`/my_model:/models/default/0000001 -p 8000:8080 -it gcr.io/cloud-automl-tables-public/model_server:latest
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. You can pull new version with command
`docker pull ...`
New version was released couple days ago so It works now, just have to wait for update.